# ubuntu filedialog.askdirectory too low version

Tags: python, ubuntu, tkinter

I was trying to call the file dialog of ubuntu to choose a directory with python3.6, and the code looks like this:

```
    from tkinter import filedialog
    filedialog.askdirectory()
```

but when i run this, a very old version file dialog shows:

[image: file dialog]

Any idea on how to call the newest file dialog of ubuntu using python?

Comment: it is not old version, it is standard theme for GTK. You would have to use theme to change it.

Answer (score 1):

It is not old version, it is standard theme for GTK. You would have to use theme to change it. But Linux has only three styles as default

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
from tkinter import filedialog

root = tk.Tk()

root.style = ttk.Style()

print(root.style.theme_names())

root.style.theme_use('clam')

filedialog.askdirectory()

root.mainloop()
```

classis/default:

[image]

clam:

[image]

alt:

[image]

You can get more themes installing module

```
pip install ttkthemes
```

And code

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
import ttkthemes

root = tk.Tk()

root.style = ttkthemes.ThemedStyle()

for i, name in enumerate(sorted(root.style.theme_names())):
    b = ttk.Button(root, text=name, command=lambda name=name:root.style.theme_use(name))
    b.pack(fill='x')

root.mainloop()
```

List of styles

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

kroc:

[image]

radiance:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The UI components provided by `tkinter` (and the underlying `tk` library) are different from the UI components provided by, say, the GTK or the Qt libraries that are probably used by your desktop.

[`tkinter` has a set of alternative widgets](https://docs.python.org/3/library/tkinter.ttk.html), that you can access with

```
from tkinter.ttk import *
```

that support the look and feel of your desktop, but (afaict) unfortunately the
`filedialog` widget is not supported.